# Thumbnail generation using iText

Tags: image, pdf, thumbnails, itext

Is it possible to generate thumbnail images from PDF files using iText?

Answer (score 1):

No.  iText will not rasterize PDF at any resolution.

Comment: But Ghostscript will.  These days thumbnails are unnecessary.  Reader/Acrobat just generate them for you on the fly.